# Accessing a field with lenses

Tags: haskell

I have the following data types:

```
data Car = Car String Integer
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data City =
  City
    { cityVehicle     :: Car
    }
  deriving (Generic, Show)

makeLensesWith abbreviatedFields ''Withdrawal
```

And I am trying to create a lambda function to filter cities by the 'price' of cars like so:

```
  filter (\city -> (city ^. vehicle . ) <= thresholdPrice) cities
```

but I'm not sure how to access the second field of `Car`

Comment: Change `Car` into a record and use `makeLenses` or `declareLenses`, or write the lenses by hand.

Comment: Lots of options. You could `makePrisms` and `_2` but personally I like `Data.Generics.Lens.Product.typed` :)

Comment: Does it have to be a read-replace lens or would a read-only accessor suffice?

Comment: A read-only would suffice!

Answer (score 2):

You can write the lenses by hand (I don't know what the fields represent, so I guessed model and price):

```
model :: Lens' Car String
model f (Car m p) = fmap (\m' -> Car m' p) (f m)

price :: Lens' Car Integer
price f (Car m p) = fmap (\p' -> Car m p') (f p)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't adopted lenses and just use accessors like such as `price(Car _ integer)= integer`. If you start with a lens from pat's answer I might even define `getPrice= price Const <&> getConst`. Better yet, you can incorporate the accessor definition in the datatype declaration. `data Car= Car{ model::String, price::Integer}` defines the accessors `model` and `price`.

Of course, packing an accessor and a modifier into a lens allows you to use the same identifier for both, but at the expense of having to hook the accessor out of the lend using `($Const) <$> getConst`, a level of complexity I've not yet learned to hide behind operators such as `(^.)`.